# Giving examples of two graphs satisfying two requirements.

Tags: logic, graph-theory, first-order-logic

> We consider class of directed graphs (self edges (=loop) are allowed).
>   The aim is: construct example of two graphs $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that:
>
> 1. for each graph $H$ with $\le 7$ nodes $G_1$ contains induced subgraph  isomorphic to $H$ only and only if $G_2$ contains induced
>      subgraph  isomorphic to $H$.
> 2. Player $1$ (spojler) has winning strategy in Game with $7$ rounds.

To my eye, is is sufficient to give $K_8$ and $K_7$, but each node has loop (edge to self).

For the first point, we know that $K_8$ contains as subgraph $K_7$, so if $K_9$ has
subgraph isomorphic to some $H=(V,_)$ such that $|V|\le 7$ so $K_8$ also.
If $K_8$ has subgraph isomorphic to some $H$ then we may say the same about $K_7$ because 
$H$ has at most $7$ nodes, we may close this $H$ in subgraph of $K_8$ which is simultatenously 
$K_7$.

For the second point. We know that in our $K_8$ each node has exactly $7$ distinct neighbours,
however in $K_7$ each node has only $6$ distinct neighbours. So, after $7$ moves of player $1$ duplicator
has no move. Simlpy, Player one choose any node of $K_8$ and then choose all its neighbours.

Tell me please, is it correct ? If not, how to fix it ?

Comment: It is unclear to me how to reconstruct the Game that is being referred to in point 2.  Please detail how this is a "first order sentence" as described in the title.

Comment: Ok, I did mistake in title. Edited.

Comment: It remains unclear what "Game" is referred to.  Ideally the body of your Question ipresents a self-contained problem statement, plus of course the context of your thoughts about it (points of interest, request for help, etc.) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(For completeness: the game the OP is talking about is the [*Ehrenfeucht-Fraisse game*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game).)

It looks to me like it takes Spoiler *eight* rounds to win: in seven moves alone, Duplicator can respond. So I don't think this works.

Comment: Ok, you are right. So lets decrease graphs - in both graps decrease number nodes by one. yeah ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Now claim 1 fails for $G_1$ . . .

Comment: Ok, maybe the same graphs as before, but without loops ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Doesn't Spoiler still need 8 moves to win?

Comment: hmm, Is it possible to rescue my solution ?

Comment: @HaskellFun I don't think so. I believe a more complicated solution is in fact necessary.